# Xen with multiple bridges

Tags: debian, virtualization, linux-networking, xen, debian-stretch

I have some issues with the following setup:

Debian Stretch (Frozen Testing) as a dom0.
I have configured thre bridges (xenbr0, xenbr1, xenbr2)
The /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
auto xenbr0
allow-hotplug xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet static
   bridge_ports eth0
   address $Host_Ip
   broadcast $Broadcast
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway $Gateway
   bridge_stp off       
   bridge_waitport 0    
   bridge_fd 0          

auto xenbr1
allow-hotplug xenbr1
iface xenbr1 inet manual
   pre-up brctl addbr $IFACE
   up ip link set $IFACE up
   post-down brctl delbr $IFACE
   down ip link set $IFACE down
  bridge_stp off
bridge_waitport 0
bridge_fd 0
```

xenbr2 Looks the same as xenbr1.
The bridge connected to eth0 works fine, the host is reachable and vms connected to it can establish their own network connections.

The issue is with the other two bridges which should create host only networks.
The interfaces in the connected vms won't come up.
Manually running

```
sudo ip link set dev eth1 up
-> RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address
```

The vif config in the vm.cfg looks the following

```
vif = [ 'ip=$PublicIP,mac=00:16:3E:28:97:28,bridge=xenbr0',
        'ip=10.3.141.1,mac=BD:5D:11:60:32:35,bridge=xenbr1',
        'ip=192.168.42.1,mac=E3:26:AE:BE:E0:39,bridge=xenbr2'
      ]
```

I currently assume, the issue is caused by a misconfiguration in the /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp

Enabled is the following:

```
(network-script network-bridge)
(vif-script vif-bridge)
```

Everything I found regarding that config file has been several (~10) years old.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper MAC-Adresses as stated here https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Networking#MAC_addresses everything from the OUI 00:16:3e:xx:xx:xx should work fine.